# From Activity to Fragment: IonWrapper error

Tags: android, android-studio

I encounter the IonWrapper problem when i'm going to convert Activity into fragment:

IonWrapper
(Context,
com.codingvisions.chat_fcm.helper.IonWrapper.WebServiceInterFace)
in IonWrapper cannot be applied
to
(FragmentActivity,
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity)

I've tried to passing getActivity two times in IonWrapper.

```java
/* Original function Activity */

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_richiesta_invio_pacco);

         customAlertDialog = new CustomAlertDialog(this);
        sharedPrefsHelper = new SharedPrefsHelper(this);
        webServices = new WebServices(this, new IonWrapper(this, this));
        sqliteDbManager = new SqliteDbManager(this);


        DataPartenzaInput = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.data_partenza_pacco);
        DimensioniInput = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.dimensioni_input);

        VaiButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vai_button);

    }

/* Function in Fragment */ 

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_richiesta_pacco, container, false);
/* .... */

   customAlertDialog = new CustomAlertDialog(getActivity());
        sharedPrefsHelper = new SharedPrefsHelper(getActivity());
        webServices = new WebServices(this, new IonWrapper(getActivity(), getActivity()));
        sqliteDbManager = new SqliteDbManager(getActivity());

/* ....*/

/* Constructor IonWrapper 

   public IonWrapper(Context context, WebServiceInterFace webServiceInterFace) {
        this.context = context;
         this.webServiceInterFace = webServiceInterFace;

    }

*/
}
```

Comment: What is `this` and `this` you passed in the Activity? (context or interface implementation or ...)

Comment: i think context

Comment: Then why you passed it two times?

Comment: Added constructor IonWrapper

Comment: I think your second `this` is not a context, therefore your `getActivity()` which is a context crashes. Please provide the constructor in the question.

Comment: Ehm i've files on pastebin but not have reputation successfully.. how can i do pass links of pastebin?

Comment: I do not know, please look at the answer that I shared.

Answer (score 0):

Implement com.codingvisions.chat_fcm.helper.IonWrapper.WebServiceInterFace in both activity as well as in fragment. And then pass this as second param when you init in fragment.